# Javascript - Limit the number to no decimals

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using following Javascript code in one of my calculations:

`var bx1 = parseFloat(tx9) * ( 70 / 100 );`

The output of `bx1` is showing in decimals. However, I want it to be no decimals. Looking for some help!

Eg. `bx1 = 700*70/100 = 489.999`. I want it either `489` or `490`, anything is fine.

Comment: Do you know what `parseFloat` does? (Floats are "decimal numbers")

Comment: try parseInt then

Comment: _italic_Not really, i'm not great with javascript, but I can include it if you can guide me._italic_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).

```
var = Math.round(parseFloat(tx9) * ( 70 / 100 ));
```

Comment: it worked like a charm! Thank you Sty

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `Math.round()`, `Math.floor()` or `Math.ceil()`:

```js
var bx1 = 489.999;
console.log(Math.floor(bx1));
console.log(Math.round(bx1));
console.log(Math.ceil(bx1));
```

- `floor()` will round down your number.
- `round()` will round your number (based on decimal value).
- `ceil()` will round up your number.